# Inner query aliasing in a correlated subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

So my understanding is that an inner query runs before an outer query. I was watching a PluralSight course on Postgresql and it was talking about correlated subqueries and I am confused. So say I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.flight_date,
       a.departure_delay_time,
       a.origin
FROM allflights a
WHERE a.flight_date = "2010-01-02"
AND a.origin = 'DEN'
AND a.departure_delay_time > (SELECT AVG(departure_delay_time)
                               FROM allflights
                              WHERE departure_delay_time > 0
                                AND a.origin = origin);
```

Now if the inner query is

```
SELECT AVG(departure_delay_time)
  FROM allflights
 WHERE departure_delay_time > 0
   AND a.origin = origin);
```

Then how does it know that a is the alias for allflights?

Comment: unqualified columns in a subquery bind to the tightest scope in which that column exists.  Surprisingly, I can't find this explicitly documented anywhere, but it does offer this commentary on an example "Qualifying c1 as fdt.c1 is only necessary if c1 is also the name of a column in the derived input table of the subquery" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html

Comment: I think of an "inner query" is a query which is embedded in the FROM list (and without LATERAL).  This is in the WHERE, so I don't think it an inner query, it is just a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True, the correlated subquery is executed before the outer `SELECT`. But that is orthogonal to the visibility of table names and aliases.

The whole query is parsed and planned ***before*** any of it is executed. Details in the chapter [***The Path of a Query***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/query-path.html) in the manual.

Comment: . . Is this really true?  Won't Postgres sometimes (at least) rewrite a correlated subquery using some `JOIN` algorithm?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: The query rewrite system kicks as step 3 in the path of a query linked above. Object names (and aliases) are already resolved in the previous step (parser stage). So the query rewrite system is just as orthogonal to the visibility of names as the order of execution.

Comment: . . Your answer says the subquery "is executed", not "parsed" before the outer `select`.

Comment: Because it is (executed before the outer `SELECT` is executed). But the parser stage is before anything is executed, and that's where all identifiers are resolved. So the order of execution is orthogonal to identifier resolution. Only correct syntax matters. Postgres "knows" that `a is the alias for [the outer] allflights`, according to SQL syntax rules, irregardless of the order of execution.